# How to change location of static file in WAR archive?

Tags: java, servlets

By default static files are located in `WEB-INF` directory (accessible as `/images/logo.png`):

```
foo.war
  WEB-INF
    web.xml
    images
      logo.png
```

I want to change the structure and use this one instead (still accessible as `/images/logo.png`):

```
foo.war
  WEB-INF
    web.xml
  static
    images
      logo.png
```

How can I do this with `web.xml`?

Comment: The default which you mentioned is not true. Files in `/WEB-INF` **are not directly accessible**. Perhaps you were using some servlet which returned them for you?

Answer (score 3):

The container will repsond with a 404 NOT FOUND error if you directly access the files under `WEB-INF`  using HTTP GET .

But now , you said you can access `WEB-INF/images/logo.png` by `/images/logo.png` , so I think your web application most probably achieve this result by some URLRewriteFilter mechainsim or by some Java code in the servlet level (eg a filter) , or by your web application 's framework . I suggest you to check your web application to see what mechanism  causes this behvaior now and configurate to your desired result accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WCC3.html,:

> A WAR has a specific directory
>   structure. The top-level directory of
>   a WAR is the document root of the
>   application. The document root is
>   where JSP pages, client-side classes
>   and archives, and static Web resources
>   are stored.
>
> The document root contains a
>   subdirectory called WEB-INF, which
>   contains the following files and
>   directories:
>
> web.xml: The Web application
>   deployment descriptor   Tag library
>   descriptor files (see Tag Library
>   Descriptors)   classes: A directory
>   that contains server-side classes:
>   servlets, utility classes, and
>   JavaBeans components   lib: A
>   directory that contains JAR archives
>   of libraries (tag libraries and any
>   utility libraries called by
>   server-side classes).
>
> You can also create
>   application-specific subdirectories
>   (that is, package directories) in
>   either the document root or the
>   WEB-INF/classes directory.

So the default behavior is what you're looking for.  Is your document root set incorrectly to serve content from WEB-INF?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a filter or [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to point `/images/*` to `/static/images/*`.

If you just want your folder structure to be `/static/images` for development time organization purposes, but the deployment URL to be `/images` -- you may need to alter your build script to copy `/static/**` to `/`.

I personally would not bother whether my static files are referred as `/static/images` or `/images` -- because they would be referred in my code (only), which I have control over.

If you are using these files in CSS and that's why you wanted the path to stay the same... better keep the images under `/static/css/images` and have the images that are referred in the CSS here. In this way, no matter where you move your CSS folder, you would not bother spoiling your CSS.